# How to use Narayana JTA 5.0.3.Final to provide support for XA transactions to web applications running inside Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, eclipselink, jta

I am trying to use JTA 1.2 outside Java EE compliant Application Server such as in Apache Tomcat, what I've tried so far is following [Mr. Jonathan Halliday's way](https://github.com/zvrablik/tomcatInfinispanSessionManager/tree/master/tomcatJBossTM), and [How to Configure Server Platform Using Java](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Configuring_a_Session_%28ELUG%29#Configuring_the_Server_Platform)

But I got following Exception

> -javax.faces.FacesException: #{utama.satu}: javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: ARJUNA016105: Could not lookup the TransactionManager
>
> -Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: ARJUNA016105: Could not lookup the TransactionManager
>
> -Caused by: javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: ARJUNA016105: Could not lookup the TransactionManager
>
> -Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [TransactionManager] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [TransactionManager].

Here is my META-INF/context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="" reloadable="true">
<Resource auth="Container" factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" name="BeanManager" type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"/>
<Transaction factory="com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.UserTransactionImple"/>
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/coba" name="jdbc/coba" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

and here is my conf/server.xml:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    ....
    <Resource name="jdbc/coba" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.jboss.jbossts.tomcat.TransactionalResourceFactory"
        XADataSourceImpl="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource"
        xa.setUser="sa"
        xa.setPassword="123456"
        xa.setURL="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=hrd;"
        />
    ....
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

this is my persistence.xml, it shows how I reref the datasource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="sungguhPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/coba</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="id.ac.ums.tomcat.JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/> 
            <property name="eclipselink.id-validation" value="NONE"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I've also built my customer org.eclipse.persistence.config.SessionCustomizer as described by official EclipseLink documentation, but I am still stuck on the same exception for last 24 hours :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't check in details impl you use but did you provide a TransactionSynchronizationRegistry? That's how @TransactionScoped is implemented

you need to provide depending your impl java:comp/TransactionManager and/or java:comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry